# On submultisets of given cardinality and bound that sum to $0$

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, decision-problem

Given multiset of integers $a_1,\dots,a_{m}$ where $|a_i|\leq\log^cm$  for some $c\in\Bbb R^+$. Is it $\mathsf{NP}$-complete to decide if there is a cardinality $\lceil m^\alpha\rceil$ submultiset for some $\alpha\in(0,1)$ whose sum is $0$?

How many submultisets of such cardinality can we expect to have vanishing sum?

Comment: Should c and α be outside the problem statement? ​ ​

Comment: Can you clarify what are the inputs here, and what are fixed?

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just do your (home-)work for you; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594/the-return-of-the-homework-question) for a relevant discussion. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]? You may also want to check out our [reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/599/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $c$ is fixed, this can be solved using dynamic programming in quasipolynomial time. We compute inductively *all* possible sums of all submultisets of size $k$ for all $k \leq \lceil m^\alpha \rceil$. Since each such sum is at most $2^{\log^c m} \lceil m^\alpha \rceil$, this algorithm runs in $O(2^{O(\log^c m)} m^{O(1)})$, which is quasipolynomial. This suggests that the problem is not NP-hard.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Total possible subsets is also quasipolynomial right?

Comment: No, it's exponential: roughly $m^{m^\alpha}$.

Comment: "Assuming that $c$ is fixed" _and_ $\lceil \hspace{-0.02 in}m^{\hspace{.03 in}\alpha}\hspace{-0.02 in}\rceil$ is computable in quasipolynomial time", this can ... time." ​ ​

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I am accepting your post but could you clarify a bit more on the counting to $m^{m^\alpha}$.

Comment: @RickyDemer good point just assume $\alpha$ is nice enough for now.

Comment: @Arul There's an explicit formula which you can use in conjunction with Stirling's formula to get a better approximation.